# Merging two XML files in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

Does anyone know how to merge two xml files in or two xmllist objects in Flex3 ActionScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Do these two xml files share any elements or attributes? 
In other words: Do you mean merging (omitting duplicates) or combining (allowing duplicates)?

Comment: I will be combining something like this into one XML file (one documents root tag):

<documents>
<document><node1>My Value 1</node1>
<node2>My Value 2</node2>
</document>
</documents>

<documents>
<document>
<node1>My Value 3</node1>
<node2>My Value 4</node2>
</document>
</documents>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to append:

```
//all items from 2 are now added to 1
for each(var item:xml in myXMLList2){
  myXMLList1.appendChild(item);
}

//all items added to new XMLlist
var myMergedXMLList:XMLList;
for each(var item:xml in myXMLList1){
  myMergedXMLList.appendChild(item);
}
for each(var item:xml in myXMLList2){
  myMergedXMLList.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: @invertedSpear Thanks for the answer, it really helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I applied part of what invertedSpear suggested and got it to work. Thank everyone for commenting/answering.

var xmlstr1:String = "My Value 1My Value 2"

var xmlstr2:String = "My Value 3My Value 4"

var xml1:XML;
var xml2:XML;

var xmlst1:XMLList;
var xmlst2:XMLList;
var xmlstMerged:XMLList = new XMLList();
var item:XML

xml1 = XML(xmlstr1);
xml2 = XML(xmlstr2);

xmlst1 = new XMLList(xml1);
xmlst2 = xml2.document;

for each(item in xmlst2){
   xmlst1.appendChild(item);
}

xmlstMerged = xml1.document;